# Toggle button doesn't work if I put the button beneath the box element

Tags: javascript, html

It's simple show and hide in javascript. If I put the click button above the div box the script works however if I put it beneath the div box it does not.

How do I make it so the order is

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Phones
      </li>
      <li>
        TV
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" class="clickme">Show</a>

$('.box').hide();

$('.clickme').each(function() {
  $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast', function() {
      $(this).prev().html($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
    });
  });
});
```

[Here's the **DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5go06xjp/22/)

Comment: Have you looked into http://api.jquery.com/toggle/?

Comment: You're using next and prev functions in your code. of course the order of the elements will be important.

Comment: next() and prev() are relative and respect current element tree. You have `$(this).next('.box')` in the handler, but when you change position of that div, it won't be next any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your clicked element (`a`) is under the `div` it is unable to detect `next()`. Use `siblings()` instead.

Change

```
$(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast', function() {
```

To

```
$(this).siblings('.box').slideToggle('fast', function() {
```

```js
$('.clickme').each(function() { 
  $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).siblings('.box').slideToggle('fast', function() {
        $(this).prev().html($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show'); 
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px/16px sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.clickme {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clickme:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Phones
    </li>
    <li>
      TV
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" class="clickme">Show</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calling the next element with class of box, but their is no box class after the button if you put it below the list. Just reference the list by calling its class:

```
$('.box').slideToggle('fast', function() {
  $(this).prev().html($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
});
```

Hope this helps;

Answer (score 0):

`$.next()`return the immediately followed siblings, therefore you cannot use that in the case.
You can try `$.siblings()` or `$.prev()`

```js
$('.box').hide(); 
$('.clickme').each(function() { 
$(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $(this).siblings('.box').slideToggle('fast', function() { $(this).prev().html($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show'); }); 
}); 
});
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px/16px sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.clickme {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clickme:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Phones
      </li>
      <li>
        TV
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" class="clickme">Show</a>
```

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in
> the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves
> the next sibling only if it matches that selector